# Watch file and write new contents to TableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How can I watch a file and whenever it is written to insert the added contents to a NSTableView as a new row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to go into all the details of exactly how to do this, but I'm guessing that the sticking point for you is probably how to monitor a file in the filesystem.  If that's the case, the answer to this question should be useful:

[Notification of changes to the iPhone's /Documents directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181821/notification-of-changes-to-the-iphones-documents-directory)

Comment: I am trying to do this with an OS X desktop application, but I would assume this can still help. Thanks