# Check if file is updated

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsfilemanager

I have iOS application. There some files in the documents directory. I need to check if these files were edited or replaced. What is the proper way to do it? Shall i some hash of the file or last edited time(how to get this time in iOS) or there is some better way to implement this?

Comment: You can surely check with its updated time. 

Go on to save the updated time to some plist and check it.

Comment: who else can edit/replace the files in the `Documents` directory in runtime beside your application...?

Comment: Itunes synchronization, you can add some files to documets directory from itunes

Comment: How can i get file edited time?

Comment: @George, in that case try to implement an existing solution for it, like **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181821/notification-of-changes-to-the-iphones-documents-directory)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this code to get the file modification date:

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDictionary* attributes = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil];

if (attributes != nil) {
    NSDate *date = (NSDate*)[attributes objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];
    NSLog(@"Last modification date: %@", [date description]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Not found");
}
```

[here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/attributesOfItemAtPath%3aerror%3a) you can find the documentation of the `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` function, and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/File_Attribute_Keys) the list of file properties you can get

Answer (score 1):

Hashing the entire file will work, but is a bit overkill for most purposes. I'd combine a few things which are quick to access:

- NSFileModificationDate
- NSFileSize
- NSFileCreationDate
- NSFileSystemFileNumber (inode number)

If you are using the NSURL-based API (iOS 4.0+), I'd use

- NSURLContentModificationDateKey (modification time)
- NSURLFileSizeKey
- NSURLCreationDateKey
- NSURLFileAllocatedSizeKey
- NSURLAttributeModificationDateKey (`st_ctime`?)

I'd at least use the the modification time and file size. The other things are things that generally do not change unless the contents change, with a couple of caveats:

- NSFileSystemFileNumber (the inode number) will likely change if the user restores from a backup.
- NSURLAttributeModificationDateKey is supposed to change when *attributes* change. If it is `st_ctime` (and I'm not entirely sure it is), it is *almost* guaranteed to catch all changes to the file, but may also catch a lot of changes that don't represent changes to the file contents. I don't know if such changes happen externally (e.g. does iTunes/iCloud backup set attributes as part of the backup process?).