# How to copy the file from document folder to photo gallery in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

I am not sure if i missed the URL in the internet. I am trying to copy or move the file [jpeg file] from Document folder to PhotoGallery in iOS. 
Is there any api available in iOS?

also,

Is there any way to set the notification handler for Document folder, where when the file is created in the document folder,my callback should get triggerd where i will move the file from document folder to Photo Gallery.

Comment: after creation complete which api you are using for saving file in document directory?that will tell you that file storing is completed.

Comment: Johny kumar, The File saving operation is asynchronous, in other way the other library saves, and we have no way to figure out polling the directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum (image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:) , nil);
```

the callback method signature is:

```
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
```

**Later edit**

If you want to get notified for file changes you can find some answers here: [Notification of changes to the iPhone's /Documents directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181821/notification-of-changes-to-the-iphones-documents-directory)