# Notification of changes to Documents directory when device locked /app not active

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdocumentdirectory

Im detecting changes in the documents directory like so https://stackoverflow.com/a/20423421/1238867

Predictively it does not monitor a change if the device is in standby/locked/app not in foreground.

I know its a longshot but I want to observe if any changes have happened to the documents directory when in background?

eg The device was in standby and connected to file sharing in iTunes, and the documents directory was altered

As the flag for allowing file sharing is read only its a bit of a conundrum

A lot of Searching on So and Google has not provided anything

Comment: why do you want to monitor the changes in the background? i mean: if you receive a notification "file XY has changed" while your app is in background, how would your app react? would you post a local notification? because if all you want to do is to update the UI when the user reopens the app later, you don't need these background notifications at all...

Comment: The purpose of the file monitoring is to delete the files transferred  if certain conditions are not met.  However these conditions are all meaningless if the app is in background.  So ideally id like to stop all file transfers if the app is not active but as the file transfer is flag either off or on in the plist with no option to change at runtime there's not much flexibility